# Problema con Arrays Java

Tags: java, clase, condiciones

Mi pregunta es la siguiente , porque yo al declarar una Array para crear una cola, y poner este codigo :

```
public void InicializarCola() {
        PrimCola=new int[100];
        indice=0;
```

Yo al poner Acolar, el cual es un metodo que posee este codigo

```
public void Acolar(int y) {
    PrimCola[indice]=y;
    indice++;
```

El programa, cuando yo pongo ej: Cola1.Acolar(1),Cola2.Acolar(2).

Me da este error "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", a que se debe?

Comment: Revisate este enlace [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que el ámbito de la variable "indice" se limita dentro del método "inicializarCola", por lo cual no puedes acceder desde un método externo como lo es "Acolar", por lo cual debes inicializar primero la variable "indice" desde fuera de los métodos.

Una propuesta seria:

```
public class Cola{
    private int indice = 0;
    private int PrimCola;

    public Cola(){
    }

    //GETTERS

    //SETTERS

    public void InicializarCola(){
        PrimCola = new int[100];
    }

    public void Acolar(int y){
        PrimCola[indice] = y;
        indice++; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo, ¿has llamado primero a tu método *inicializarCola()*? Yo he usado tu código y me funciona sin problemas. Ya he supuesto que la variable **indice**, al igual que la matriz **primCola** las has creado fuera del método.

```
public void iniciarCola() {
        primCola= new int[100];
        indice=0;
    }

public void acolar(int y) {
    primCola[indice]=y;
    System.out.println(primCola[indice]);
    indice++;
}
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Matrices m = new Matrices();
    m.iniciarCola();
    m.acolar(1);
    m.acolar(2);
    m.acolar(3);
}
```